# Sunburst with multiple categories per entry

Tags: dc.js, sunburst-diagram

Hi I would like to ask a question. when using sunburst chart of dc.js data have to be of the form:

```
file         value
A/a1/a2/a3   1000
A/a4/a2/a1   2500
B/b1/b2/b3   1200
C/c1/c2/c3   1300
```

and accordinding to https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/sunburst-cat.html a sunburst can be created. 
But how do i handle the case where:

```
File                               value
A/a1/a2/a3,B/b1/b2/b3              2000
B/b1/b2/b3,C/c1/c2/c3              2200
B/b1/b4/b5                         3000
A/a1/a2/a3                         1000
```

any help will be greatly appreciated!
thanks